# Media Queries not working on ie7

Tags: responsive-design, media

I am using media queries and its not working on `ie7` i use `respond.js` and its start working on `ie8` but still not working on `ie7` so any solution for that thanks. I also try other ways which i found here but still not working for me.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
 <link href="http://externalcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

nternet Explorer 8 or older doesn't support media query. You can use media-queries.js or respond.js to add media query support in IE.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

jsut check the the link. [Css3 IE 7 and 8](http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/)

Comment: i already using respond.js but it only work in ie8 not in ie7. and i also try media-queries.js but still same result

Comment: its css3-mediaqueries.js